# 4th Order Brownian Motion Martingale

Tags: brownian-motion, martingale, stochastic

I understand the first order MG of brownian motion is Bt.. the second order is Bt^2 - t and the third order is bt^3 - 3tBt. How can I find the fourth and beyond order of a Brownian Motion Martingale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the expansion of
$$ \exp(\sigma B_t - \sigma^2t/2) $$
in the power of $\sigma$.
The general $n$-th order martingale is expressed by [the probabilist's Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials).

The 4th order is polynomial is $x^4 - 6x^2 + 3$, so the margingale is
$$ B_t^4 - 6t B_t^2 + 3 t^2.$$